# compiling mpirun and mpif90 for a different platform (crosscompiling?)

Tags: compilation, fortran, mpi, cross-compiling

I have a system A (aka Host) with compilers and a system B (aka Target) where I would like to run a MPI application. On system B there is no compiler or mpirun. I would like to do the following: compile mpirun (from openmpi) on system A and then using it on system B (with executable compiled on system A). I have never compiled for a different platform. Can this thing work? What do I do with shared libraries? I see that mpirun links to :

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00002aaaaaaab000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003a89e00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003a89600000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003a89a00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003a89200000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003a88e00000)
```

do I have to statically link mpirun to libraries on system A? How do I do that?

---

Also, I would like to know if I can compile mpif90 on system A, so I can use it directly to compile programs on system B. Keep in mind that there is no compiler on system B, and I am not willing to install them

---

output of `uname -a` on Host

```
Linux host 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 19:48:22 GMT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

output of `uname -a` on Target

```
Linux target 2.6.35-32-server #67-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 5 21:13:25 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

so far I have tried to compile with the following configuration

```
CC=icc
FC=ifort
CXX=icpc
LDFLAGS=-static-intel

./configure --prefix=/gpfs/data/garzilli/data/local/openmpi-1.8.4-cc/ --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --enable-static --disable-shared
```

I know that in this case I am not technically cross-compiling, because host and build coincide, in principle they could be different. Maybe, should I also set `--target`, because I am compiling a compiler?

Comment: How much do the two computers differ? What operating system (and kernel version) they have?

Comment: I added the output of `uname -a` on both host and target, what else do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to compile on one platform and execute on the other.  I do this often with Fortran binaries compile with ifort and mpif90. I just ran a test where I compiled an executable with the ifort compiler and mpif90 on OpenSUSE 2.6.34 kernel x86_64 and ran it on a Amazon Linux kernel version 3.14 x86_64 that had no mpi libs installed.

The problem is that without mpirun (or mpiexec), you will only be able to run a single instance of the program.  So, if you have to launch multiple instances, you will need something like mpirun on the other machine (system B) to launch the multiple instances.

Comment: You are lucky that the server is newer and not older. I usually encounter old versions of GLIBC on HPC clusters and it is a big pain to get any binary from a more recent desktop distro to work there.

Comment: But then getting it to work with the local queue manager and the Infiniband drivers will be very difficult anyway.

Comment: The experience I have had with running on older machines is that they may not be 64-bit, or they are using an older version of the C library.  From what I could tell, both the versions mentioned were using libc6, and they are both x86_64 machines.